# распаковка генерируемых элементов в генераторах Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

у меня возникла проблема с распаковкой элементов, во время их создания в генераторе

проблемная часть кода:

```py
test_markup = [*create_item_buttons(item)      # return: nested lists
               if item                         # Error
               else create_empty_row()
               for item in test_list_of_items]
```

весь код:

```py
'''
ALL_ITEMS : list : list of all items
screening : func : (keyboard) : screening keyboard from create_keyboard
create_keyboard : func : (*markup) : get rows(lists) of buttons
button : list : manually : ['<label>', after_click]
after_click : manually :
    if : list : [func, call_for_func]
    if : func : function, activated after clicking
'''

from random import choice

def create_item_buttons(item):
    '''
    :return: two rows of clickable buttons for item
    '''
    return [
      [
        [item.name, item.details]],                                          # row 1
      [
        ['option1', [print,'option1']], ['option2', [print,'option2']]]]     # row 2

def create_empty_row():
    '''
    :return: one row of a non-clickable button
    '''
    return ['', [print,'IGNORE']]

get_item = lambda: choice([choice(ALL_ITEMS), None])

test_list_of_items = [get_item() for _ in range(5)]
test_markup = [*create_item_buttons(item)
               if item                                   # Error
               else create_empty_row()
               for item in test_list_of_items]

screening(create_keyboard(*markup))
```

итог:

```py
if item
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя использовать распаковку в генераторе списка, чтобы создать сразу несколько элементов. Вам придётся делать это как-то по-другому.

Кажется, что-то подобное должно для вас сработать:

```
test_markup = []
for item in test_list_of_items:
    if item:
        test_markup.extend(
            create_item_buttons(item))
    else:
        test_markup.append(
            create_empty_row())
```